# How to know a certain disk's format(is FAT32 or NTFS)

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I am programing under windows, c++, mfc
How can I know disk's format by path such as "c:\".
Does windows provide such APIs?

Comment: GetVolumeInformation() can tell you if a volume supports encryption/compression/hardlinks etc. You should use those flags and not the name of the filesystem if you need to make sure the volume supports a specific feature. (Remember NTFS/FAT* are not the only filesystems on windows, even tho they are the only ones supported out of the box)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Win32API function ::GetVolumeInformation is what you are looking for.

From MSDN:

[GetVolumeInformation Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364993(VS.85).aspx)

```
BOOL WINAPI GetVolumeInformation(
    __in_opt   LPCTSTR lpRootPathName,
    __out      LPTSTR lpVolumeNameBuffer,
    __in       DWORD nVolumeNameSize,
    __out_opt  LPDWORD lpVolumeSerialNumber,
    __out_opt  LPDWORD lpMaximumComponentLength,
    __out_opt  LPDWORD lpFileSystemFlags,
    __out      LPTSTR lpFileSystemNameBuffer, // Here
    __in       DWORD nFileSystemNameSize
);
```

Example:

```
TCHAR fs [MAX_PATH+1];
::GetVolumeInformation(_T("C:\\"), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &fs, MAX_PATH+1);
// Result is in (TCHAR*) fs
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is GetVolumeInformation.

```
TCHAR szVolumeName[100]    = "";
TCHAR szFileSystemName[10] = "";
DWORD dwSerialNumber       = 0;
DWORD dwMaxFileNameLength  = 0;
DWORD dwFileSystemFlags    = 0;

if(::GetVolumeInformation("c:\\",
                            szVolumeName,
                            sizeof(szVolumeName),
                            &dwSerialNumber,
                            &dwMaxFileNameLength,
                            &dwFileSystemFlags,
                            szFileSystemName,
                            sizeof(szFileSystemName)) == TRUE)
  {
    cout << "Volume name = " << szVolumeName << endl
         << "Serial number = " << dwSerialNumber << endl
         << "Max. filename length = " << dwMaxFileNameLength
         << endl
         << "File system flags = $" << hex << dwFileSystemFlags
         << endl
         << "File system name = " << szFileSystemName << endl;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

[GetVolumeInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364993(VS.85).aspx) will give you what you need.  It will return the name of the drive format in lpFileSystemNameBuffer.

If you want a nice wrapper around it, you might want to look at Microsoft's [CVolumeMaster](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164038.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The Win32_LogicalDisk class in WMI has a FileSystem Property that exposes that information.